# The result of keras fit_generator is not the same as fit

Tags: tensorflow, keras, neural-network

This is my code, The shape of my training set is (5000000, 30, 223), and the shape of my test set is (2500000, 30, 223)

```
first_input = Input(shape=(None,30, 223), name='seq_input', batch_shape=(None,30,  223))

x = BatchNormalization()(first_input)

# x = CuDNNGRU(30,return_sequences=True)(x)
x = Conv1D(128, (2),activation=LeakyReLU(), padding="same")(x)

x1 = Conv1D(64, (2),activation=LeakyReLU(), padding="same")(x)

x2 = Conv1D(32, (2),activation=LeakyReLU(), padding="same")(x)

# x2 = Add()([x,x2])

x = BatchNormalization()(x)
merged = Flatten()(x)


output_1 = Dense(1, activation='linear', name='output_1')(merged)


model = Model(inputs=[first_input], outputs=output_1)

model.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Nadam(lr=(1e-3)), loss='mse')


def minibatches(inputs=None, targets=None, batch_size=None):
   while 1: 
       assert len(inputs) == len(targets)
       for start_idx in range( 0,len(inputs) - batch_size, batch_size ):
          excerpt = slice(start_idx, start_idx + batch_size)
          yield inputs[excerpt], targets[excerpt]

from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping, ModelCheckpoint, ReduceLROnPlateau
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint, ReduceLROnPlateau, EarlyStopping


cb_Early_Stop=EarlyStopping( monitor='val_loss',patience=10, restore_best_weights=True)
batch_size=512
lr = keras.callbacks.ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss', factor=0.8, patience=2, verbose=0, mode='min', min_delta=0.00001)


History  = model.fit_generator(minibatches(trainX,trainY,batch_size),
                                steps_per_epoch=len(trainX)//batch_size,
                               epochs=1,
                              validation_data = minibatches(testX,testY,batch_size) ,
                               validation_steps = len(testX)//(batch_size),
                               verbose = 2,
                               callbacks=[cb_Early_Stop,lr])
Epoch 1/30
 - 355s - loss: 2.5457 - val_loss: 1.5335






from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error

pred = model.predict(testX, batch_size)

print(mean_squared_error(testY, pred))
```

> ```
> the result is `17.763950379588405` not same as `1.5335`
> ```

When I use fit, the results of these two methods of calculating mse are the same.The actual effect of fit is better. The actual effect mentioned here is mean_squared_error of sklearn, although the valid loss of fit is 4.96. The actual mse is also 4.96, the fit generator shows 1.53, but the actual is 17.76. for train set,fit is convered to  2.5. for valid set,fit is convered to only 4.96. So what's the problem?

Comment: does the fit generator is also convered to 2.5? If you perform prediction, you do it on minibatches and sum all of the batches and divide for the number of of batch to get your final result. Can you loop the prediction with random batches in prediction for testing?

Comment: So, obviously, the model train on fit_generator does not reach the lowest loss yet. The difference can be caused by random init of the weights. You can try to train longer and adjust a bit for fit generator

Comment: For train set,fit  is convered to 2.5,which is similar as fit generator . for valid set,fit  is convered to only 4.96

Comment: Your test is not totally converged, then when you just count one batch in predict, the error can be quite high, even more than 4.96 (as 4.96 is the mean number)

Comment: also, the way you divide minibatch is not randomized, while when u use fit, the batch will be random sampled

Comment: The actual effect of fit is better. The actual effect mentioned here is mean_squared_error of sklearn, although the valid loss of fit is 4.96. The actual mse is also 4.96, the fit generator shows 1.53, but the actual is 17.76

Comment: On the SKlearn, they use prediction comparing with the true label. Why did you predict a batch of X, but the calculate the different with Y label? It should be pred = model.predict(testY, batch_size) and also, you may want to set the mse with square = False

Comment: Which code  I predicted a batch of X, but the calculated label is different from the Y label？

Comment: pred = model.predict(testX, batch_size)

print(mean_squared_error(testY, pred))

Comment: you leave it in the question below the script

Comment: I think the batch size in the prediction has no effect on the mse. The batch size predicted in keras seems to only affect the prediction speed. Am I wrong?

Comment: Yes, I think so, but you can check manually whether it is switched your data order or not. ie: you can choose a small batch size =4 and take the top 8 result compare with model.evaluate only top 8 results whether they are similar or not.

Answer (score 0):

I leave the results to those who need it. My problem may occur because my generator does not have shuffle. Here is an example I gave:

```
def minibatches(inputs=None, targets=None, batch_size=None):
   np.random.seed(5)  
   while 1: 
      assert len(inputs) == len(targets)
      indices = np.arange(len(inputs))
      np.random.shuffle(indices)

      for start_idx in range( 0,len(inputs) - batch_size, batch_size ):
         excerpt = indices[start_idx:start_idx + batch_size]
         yield inputs[excerpt], targets[excerpt]
```

Please note that my code may ignore the last batch, because if the last batch does not reach a certain batch length, if anyone can help me modify it, then I would appreciate it very much.

Comment: You first have to shuffle the data first by
`shuffle_order = np.radndom.permutation(len(inputs))

   inputs_shuffle = inputs[shuffle_order]

   target_shuffle = targets[shuffle_order]`

Then you can take the indices like the way you did, but if the indices should be

`indices = np.arange((len(inputs)+batch_size)//bath_size)`

Then with your last batch that you don't have efficient amount of data, you just need to take all of the end of that batch_size + a little random data from the rest.